# FPL class problem into P class problem?

Tags: time-complexity

Say I have an FPL class problem with the complexity O(2^k * n). If I limit the problem so that k is a known factor (for example 150). Then the complexity becomes O(2^150 * n). I have learnt that constants get removed from the complexity equation. Which means the complexity should now be O(n). Does this mean the limitation I set to the FPL problem turned it into a problem in class P?